Resolving Celery Timeout Issues on Heroku: 504 Errors for Long-Running Asynchronous Tasks
I have a Django v5.0.6 application (Python v3.12) in which I integrated Celery v5.4 to run asynchronous tasks, such as generating images via the OpenAI API, which takes about 2 minutes.
The entire setup is deployed on Heroku. Here is the content of my Procfile:
web: gunicorn mngrs_backend.wsgi --timeout 600
worker: celery -A mngrs_backend worker -l info --time-limit=7200

However, after 30 seconds, I get the following error in the logs:

I am looking to increase the delay to avoid a timeout.
Here are the attempts I made without success:

Added --timeout 600 in the gunicorn command in the Procfile

Added --time-limit=7200 in the celery command in the Procfile

Added a timeout to the API request: requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers, timeout=600)

Modified the configuration in celery.py
  app = Celery("mngrs_backend")
  app.conf.update(
      task_soft_time_limit=60 * 10,  
      task_time_limit=60 * 12,  
  )


Added in the project settings:
  CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {
      "visibility_timeout": 60 * 60 * 2,  # 2 hours
  }



Locally with Celery, I do not have any timeout issues. I contacted Heroku support, but they told me the problem is with my Celery configuration.
Does anyone have a solution?
